# Comparing string with an array but it gave me an error

Tags: c

I wanted to compare the string that I scanned with all the id's that existed in the array id, but somehow it gave me an error

```
int main()
{
    int i, try;
    char* id[8], * pass[8];
    char inp_id, inp_pass;
    id[0] = "id1"; ///Sample ID and pass
    id[1] = "id2";
    id[2] = "id3";
    pass[0] = "pass1";
    pass[1] = "pass2";
    pass[2] = "pass3";
    for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        printf("ID:");
        scanf("%s", &inp_id);
        printf("Password:");
        scanf("%S", &inp_pass);
        if (strcmp(inp_id, id[i]) != 0) ///It said the error is here
        {
            printf("Correct ID");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `inp_id` is only one character, but you seem to be under the false impression that it's a string.

Comment: It would have been good to include the exact error message in your question, just saying "gave me an error" is a bit vague.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask].  [Edit] your post to include the error.

Comment: Joseph You're right! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`inp_id` is a char, not an array nor a pointer, thus you are passing a variable with an incorrect type to `strcmp()`. There are other issues that I have corrected in your program, see below, for example, the return value for a successful comparison for `strcmp()` is 0, not different than 0. `id` and `pass` didn't have enough space to hold the information, and strings should be copied by a function similar to `strcpy()` unless you are assigning it upon declaration.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i, try;
    char id[3][8], pass[3][8];
    char inp_id[8], inp_pass[8];
    strcpy(id[0], "id1"); ///Sample ID and pass
    strcpy(id[1], "id2");
    strcpy(id[2], "id3");
    strcpy(pass[0], "pass1");
    strcpy(pass[1], "pass2");
    strcpy(pass[2], "pass3");
    for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        printf("ID:");
        scanf("%8s", inp_id);
        printf("Password:");
        scanf("%8s", inp_pass);
        if (strcmp(inp_id, id[i]) == 0) ///It said the error is here
        {
            printf("Correct ID\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```